# Deploying hapijs api to heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, hapi.js

I've got a hapijs server working with mongo (mongolabs, to be specific) that works perfectly fine locally but when deployed it gives me an Application Error. Here's a snippet with my logs:

```
2015-12-06T17:30:17.782595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-12-06T17:30:17.911448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=angular-scaffold-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=616df52f-a5fb-482f-9f8b-cb2daab07142 fwd="161.0.214.224" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-06T17:30:19.839856+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=angular-scaffold-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=0b623277-20d6-4e74-ab21-dbd31850332b fwd="161.0.214.224" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I tried every possible answer i've found to this same problem, from changing the port so heroku can bind it automatically to changing the mongodb to work with mongolabs, removed the IP from the server creation and a lot of other things I can't recall right now. Here's my server:

```
var hapi = require('hapi');
var inert = require('inert');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var routes = require('./routes');
var auth = require('hapi-auth-cookie');

var server = new hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    port: ~~process.env.PORT | 8000,
    routes: { cors: {
                    credentials: true,
                    origin: ["*"]
                } }
});
//changed these so theres no real data on the user/password part, but I got the real thing in my server
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<password>@ds049104.mongolab.com:49104/angular-scaffold'); 

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log("Connection with database succeeded.");
});

server.register([inert, auth], function(err){

  server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
    password: 'secretpasswordforencryption',
    cookie: 'angular-scaffold-cookie',
    ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Set session to 1 day
    isSecure: false
  });

    server.route(routes.endpoints);

    server.start(function () {
        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you get any logs from hapi?

Comment: No, nothing. The only other thing I see here is a log entry that says "Not Found" (don't think that's from Hapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I had errors on the path in my start script on the package.json
What I had was

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js"
  },
```

while there was no directory called server in my app, so I only changed to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
```

and the app deployed correctly. 
(had the same error deploying the front-end for the same application, only that with the postinstall script)